# How to change the font while emailing from the terminal

Tags: fonts, ssmtp

From the terminal I send an emailout to myself:

```
  :$ ssmtp 3kstc@StackExchange.com < my_email_text.txt
```

my_email_text.txt contains the following:

```
To: 3kstc@StackExchange.com
From: 3kstc@StackExchange.com
Subject: Be Happy!

Hello World!
```

**Q:** Is there a way of setting the font from whatever the default is to a specific font type when this type of email is sent out?

Answer (score 4):

An email itself contains nothing but plain text. Therefore there is no such thing as a font in an email.

You only can decide the content of that text. If you simply send **plain text** as you did above the reader of the mail can set his terminal or mail reader to a specific font to display that text.

You can also send **html code** in your mail, which again is noting but text. In that case the reader of your mail has either to manually interpret your html code or use a mail reader which renders your mail like a web page.

It is also possible to add **both** a plain text and html version to your mail in this case the reader can decide whether it shows the plain text or html part of your mail.

If you want more details maybe [RFC 1341](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1341.txt) will answer all of them.

Comment: in other words there is no way of, writing bold, underlining or having a specific size font, as the mailing is [in] 'plain text'

Comment: exactly that is the meaning of "plain text" :)